Formula in "On the Number of Prime Numbers less than a Given Quantity"
In Riemann's Famous paper "On the Number of Prime Numbers less than a Given Quantity" in page 6 he writes:
$$-\log\Pi\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)=\lim\left(\sum_{n=1}^{n=m}\log\left(1+\frac{s}{2n}\right)-\frac{s}{2}\log m\right)$$
for $m=\infty$, where $\Pi\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)$ is the way he denotes the Gamma function, I care to note that:
$$\Pi\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)=\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}+1\right)$$
I am struggling to understand how to obtain this formula, I tried using the fact that:
$$\Gamma\left(s\right)=\frac{1}{s}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{1+\frac{s}{n}}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^s\right]$$
for $\frac{s}{2}+1$ but I cant't seem to obtain the same result.
Can someone help?

I believe it's a combination of the Weierstrass form for the gamma function (see https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html equation (15)) and the usual harmonic number/log definition of $\gamma$.
